# How To Check The Balance Of A Mnemonic Key With Python?

Tags: python, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

Does anyone know how to check the balance of a mnemonic key with python? I couldn't find any information online on how to do this. It's like it's impossible to do.

Comment: Seed phrases do not have balance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate address from your menmonic and query a node to get balance

One extra piece of information apart from the mnemonic that is required is its HD path , alot of wallets follow BIP44 path format , you can find path for mst
coins here

https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md